# Spring controller get multidimensional array as post parameters

Tags: java, spring, post, multidimensional-array

I have a form that can be dynamically edited - the user can add/remove rows and information
The structure is this:
every element in the multidimensional array has the following elements:

1. `id_material`
2. `id_detail`

and in the rows that can be added/removed within the form:

- name
- quantity
- file

the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myData[id_material][0]" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="myData[id_detail][0]" value="456">
<input type="text" name="myData[ime_detail][0][1]" value="foo">
<input type="text" name="myData[quantity][0][1]" value="1">
<input type="file" name="myData[file][0][1]" accept=".pdf, .jpg, .dxf">

<input type="hidden" name="myData[id_material][1]" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="myData[id_detail][1]" value="456">
<input type="text" name="myData[ime_detail][1][1]" value="foo">
<input type="text" name="myData[quantity][1][1]" value="1">
<input type="file" name="myData[file][1][1]" accept=".pdf, .jpg, .dxf">
<input type="text" name="myData[ime_detail][1][2]" value="bar">
<input type="text" name="myData[quantity][1][2]" value="2">
<input type="file" name="myData[file][1][2]" accept=".pdf, .jpg, .dxf">
```

My Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = myURL, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public @ResponseBody error save(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse resp,
        @PathVariable("locale") String loc,
        @RequestParam Map<String, Object> params) {

    System.out.println("save() method invoked");

    return null;
}
```

However, the controller method is never invoked when the form is submited. I have tried wrapping the parameters in a class like this:

```
public class CustomWrapper {
    private Map<String, Object> customMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    public Map<String, Object> getCustomMap() {
        return customMap;
    }
    public void setCustomMap(Map<String, Object> customMap) {
        this.customMap = customMap;
    }
}
```

still its not invoked. Do you guys have any idea how to properly submit the form?